# Add item to RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

At present, I have an application with a `RecyclerView` in a fragment. My problem currently is that I am not able to add an element to this `RecyclerView`. I am currently using a `DialogFragment` to get input from the user, and when the user pushes the "create" button, a method in the `MainActivity` is called

CreateRecipeFragment `DialogFragment` class:

```
public class CreateRecipeFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public CreateRecipeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    EditText newName, newIngredients, newMethod, newNotes;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_recipe, null);

        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout

        Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
        final String parentBook = mArgs.getString("parentBook");

        builder.setView(view)
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("Create Recipe", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        newName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
                        newIngredients = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editIngredients);
                        newMethod = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editMethod);
                        newNotes = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editNotes);

                        String recipe_name = newName.getText().toString();
                        String recipe_ingredients = newIngredients.getText().toString();
                        String recipe_method = newMethod.getText().toString();
                        String recipe_notes = newNotes.getText().toString();

                        Recipe recipe = new Recipe(recipe_name, "Description", recipe_ingredients, recipe_method, recipe_notes, parentBook);

                        Log.d("Name:  ", recipe_name);
                        MainActivity callingActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                        callingActivity.addRecipeFromFragment(recipe);
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        CreateRecipeFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {


    }

    }
```

The `onClick` listener in the fragment that has the `RecyclerView`

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CreateRecipeFragment createRecipeFragment = new CreateRecipeFragment();
            MainActivity callingActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            createRecipeFragment.show(callingActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogBOX2");
            recipes.add(callingActivity.tempRecipe);
            m2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // m2Adapter is the adapter for the RecyclerView in the fragment
        }
    });
```

The add Method in the `MainActivity`

```
public Recipe tempRecipe;
public void addRecipeFromFragment(Recipe recipe) {
    dbManager.addRecipe(recipe);
    tempRecipe = recipe;

}
```

`addRecipe` method in `DBManager` class (SQLite)

```
public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME, recipe.getRecipeTitle());
    values.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION, recipe.getRecipeDescription());
    values.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENTS, recipe.getIngredients());
    values.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_METHOD, recipe.getMethod());
    values.put(COLUMN_RECIPE_NOTES, recipe.getNotes());
    if (COLUMN_IMAGE_ID != null) {
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE_ID, recipe.getImageId());
    }
    values.put(COLUMN_PARENT_BOOK, recipe.getParentBook());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_RECIPES, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no point in creating dialog fragment when you are using alert dialog inside it. You can remove the Alert dialog creation code from the dialog fragment and have the custom layout for dialog fragment as per requirement. This is same as fragments . 
Second you should use Interfaces to communicate from fragment to activity.Have a look at the below link
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Third have the recycler adapter globally in the activity and have public method in the adapter which will add the newly added item to the list add call notifyItemInserted(0);
I can also see that you are inserting data in db . If so you can write a public method in adapter and get all the recipies from db and put it into List model maintained in the adpater and call notifyDataSetChanged